# Weblogic: How to prevent "A mismatch exists between the bean code and generated code" when deploying

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I use WLST (scripted) automatic deployment on WebLogic 12c (12.1.3 - latest). This automatically deploys my enterprise application on a managed server (not admin server).

Note: The error also occurs if I execute the deployment manually.

Sometimes I get this exception:

```
A mismatch exists between the bean code and generated code. ...
```

My application does not get deployed then. This cannot be fixed by deploying again, only deleting the deployment with the help of the AdminServer console works reliably.

Any ideas how this is triggered and/or I can "fix" (heal) it reliably?

I have seen this error being logged and reported numerous times even with older versions of Weblogic, but no possible solution in sight.

Comment: When you use WLST, have you tried undeploy->activate and the deploy->activate? I have seen some caching issues when you try to redeploy over the top of an existing deploy.

Comment: I did not try this indeed, let me check. if this works you get a free coffee (you will have to visit my office, though :-) )

Comment: Woho, it worked! Could you make your comment an answer? Then I can tick it as such for later reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes weblogic has caching issues when you try to redeploy over an existing app. Trying an undeploy and redeploy normally corrects it:

```
undeploy(appName=application_name);
save()
activate(300000, "block='true'")

deploy(appName=application_name, path=deployment_artifact, targets=target_names, planPath=deployment_plan);
save()
activate(300000, "block='true'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try to clear the cache as described here: https://www.funoracleapps.com/2022/06/how-to-clear-weblogic-cache.html